# Python не видит библиотеку после установки

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, модули

После установки библиотеки и попытки запуска кода пайтон выдает что такая библиотека не установлена. Я хочу сделать бота для discord, использую windows 10 и пайтон 2.9 хотя проверял и на последней версии - та же ошибка.

Вот мой код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Working')

bot.run('тут у меня токен бота')
```

Вот вывод в консоль:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "путь к файлу", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

А это выводит после попытки установки библиоткеи:

```
Requirement already satisfied: discord in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py>=1.7.3 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from discord) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (3.7.4.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (3.2)
```

Не работает также библиотеки selenium и pyautogui , другие не проверял(все которые установлены изначально, time например , работют)

Comment: pycharm ? или где код пишите

Comment: sublime text 3.

Comment: В "путях" нет случаем русских символов?  USERNAME подразумевает вы скрыли имя пользователя. Не на русском случайно?

Comment: Нет, не на русском, но всё равно спасибо что пытаетесь мне помочь)

Comment: пробовали перезапускать sublime text?

Comment: Да пробывал, также перезапускал консоль, переустанавливал пайтон, перезагружал компьютер.

Answer (score 1):

Я долго думал что привело к ошибке, в итоге выяснил что у меня установлено сразу 3 версии пайтон. удалив 2 и проведя обновление последней у меня всё сработало. Спасибо всем кто пытались мне помочь! Для тех кто столкнулся с такой проблемой - удалите пайтон начисто и скачайте последний релиз. Всем удачи с программированием!